# codeigniter pagination with routes

Tags: php, codeigniter, routes, pagination

hello i have pagination code

```
//$this->output->enable_profiler(TRUE);
 $this->load->library('pagination');
 $this->load->model('dbs');
$config['base_url'] = site_url('cp/my_walls/');
$config['per_page'] = 5; 
$config['num_links'] = 3;
$config['uri_segment'] = 3                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            ;
$config['total_rows'] = $this->dbs->get_walls_count_by_user();
$this->pagination->initialize($config); 
$curr = ($this->uri->segment(3)) ? $this->uri->segment(3) : 0;
        $data['title'] = 'User control Panel';
        $data['walls'] = $this->dbs->get_walls_by_user($config["per_page"],$curr); // get limited posts
```

also i have route for this url

```
$route['cp/my_walls'] = "main/my_uploaded_wallpapers";
$route['cp/my_walls/(:any)'] = "main/my_uploaded_wallpapers/$1";
```

this working by deafault, its getting limited 5 post.

but i click page 2 in pagination links its no more working

```
url: site.com/cp/my_walls     - working
url: site.com/cp/my_walls/10     - not working
```

Comment: What does `var_dump($config['total_rows'])` output?

Comment: @cryptic ツ int(1241)

get_walls_count_by_user();  this function working

Comment: When you mean `site.com/cp/my_walls/10` is not working what exactly is happening? Also, do you have any other routes or .htaccess rules that you can update your question with so we can see if there may be a conflict somewhere?

Comment: try switching the lines in your route & see if that makes any difference.

Answer (score -1):

Use `$this->uri->rsegment(n)` instead of `$this->uri->segment(n)`

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
 $route['news/(:num)'] = "news/index";
```